# Unmanaged C++ Unit testing in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, mfc

I want to create a managed C++ unit test project to test an unmanaged MFC project. I have read [msujaws](http://msujaws.wordpress.com/2009/05/06/unit-testing-mfc-with-mstest/)'s procedural and followed it. I implemented a test method to test the return string of a function like so:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TxStats.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <atlstr.h>

#pragma managed

#using <mscorlib.dll>
#using <System.dll>
#using <system.data.dll>

using namespace std;
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Text;
using namespace System::Text::RegularExpressions;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::TestTools::UnitTesting;

namespace AUnitTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public ref class TxStatsTest
    {
    private:
        TestContext^ testContextInstance;

    public: 
        /// <summary>
        ///Gets or sets the test context which provides
        ///information about and functionality for the current test run.
        ///</summary>
        property Microsoft::VisualStudio::TestTools::UnitTesting::TestContext^ TestContext
        {
            Microsoft::VisualStudio::TestTools::UnitTesting::TestContext^ get()
            {
                return testContextInstance;
            }
            System::Void set(Microsoft::VisualStudio::TestTools::UnitTesting::TestContext^ value)
            {
                testContextInstance = value;
            }
        };

        #pragma region Additional test attributes
        //
        //You can use the following additional attributes as you write your tests:
        //
        //Use ClassInitialize to run code before running the first test in the class
        //[ClassInitialize()]
        //static void MyClassInitialize(TestContext^ testContext) {};
        //
        //Use ClassCleanup to run code after all tests in a class have run
        //[ClassCleanup()]
        //static void MyClassCleanup() {};
        //
        //Use TestInitialize to run code before running each test
        //[TestInitialize()]
        //void MyTestInitialize() {};
        //
        //Use TestCleanup to run code after each test has run
        //[TestCleanup()]
        //void MyTestCleanup() {};
        //
        #pragma endregion 

        [TestMethod]
        void TestGetTxRateStr()
        {
            /* str to CString

                CManagedClass* pCManagedClass = new CManagedClass();
                pCManagedClass->ShowMessage(strMessage);

                char* szMessage = (char*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(strMessage);
                CUnmanagedClass cUnmanagedClass; cUnmanagedClass.ShowMessageBox(szMessage);
                Marshal::FreeHGlobal((int)szMessage);

            */
            CString out = TxStats::GetTxRateStr(1024);
            // convert between MFC and .NET String implementations
            String ^ myManagedString = Marshal::PtrToStringAnsi((IntPtr) (char *) out.GetBuffer());
            String ^ ret = myManagedString ;///gcnew String( );
            Regex ^ matStr = gcnew Regex("1024 KB/s");
            StringAssert::Matches(ret, matStr);
        }
    };
}
```

That tests the code in a DIFFERENT project that looks like this:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
#include "TxStats.h"

TxStats::TxStats()
{
}
/*
 This method returns a data rate string formatted in either Bytes, KBytes, MBytes or GBytes per sec
 from an int of the bytes per second.
*/
CString TxStats::GetTxRateStr(__int64 Bps)
{
 enum DataUnits dunit;
 const __int64 dataSizes[]= { 0x1,        // 2 ^ 0
         0x400,      // 2 ^ 10
         0x100000,   // 2 ^ 20
         0x40000000};// 2 ^ 30
 const char *dataStrs[] = { "B/s",
          "KB/s",
          "MB/s",
          "GB/s"};
 CString out;
 double datarate;
 bool finish = false;
 for ( dunit = A_KBYTE; dunit <= LARGER_THAN_BIGGEST_UNIT; dunit = DataUnits(dunit+1) ) 
 {
  if ( dunit == LARGER_THAN_BIGGEST_UNIT )
  {
   if (dataSizes[dunit - 1] <= Bps )
   {
    //Gigabytes / sec
    datarate = Bps / ((double) dataSizes[dunit - 1]);
    out.Format("%4.2f %s", datarate, dataStrs[dunit - 1]);
    finish = true;
    break;
   }
  }
  else
  {
   if (Bps < dataSizes[dunit])
   {
    //(Kilo, Mega)bytes / sec
    datarate = Bps / ((double) dataSizes[dunit - 1]);
    out.Format("%4.2f %s", datarate, dataStrs[dunit - 1]);
    finish = true;
    break;
   }
  }
 }
 if (! finish)
 {
  out.Format("%s", "Unknown!");
 }
 return out.GetBuffer();
}


void TxStats::BytesToSizeStr(__int64 bytes, CString &out)
{
 if (bytes < 0)
 {
  out = "Err";
 }
 else if (bytes == 0)
 {
  out = "0B";
 }
 else
 {
  CString size;
  CString byteChar = "B";
  CString unit;
  int val;
  if (bytes < 1024)
  {
   //Bytes
   unit = "";
   val = (int)bytes;
  }
  else if ( (bytes >> 10) < 1024 )
  {
   //Kilobytes
   unit = "K";
   __int64 div = 1 << 10;
   val = (int) (bytes / ((double) div ));
  }
  else if ( (bytes >> 20) < 1024 )
  {
   //Megabytes
   unit = "M";
   __int64 div = 1 << 20;
   val = (int) (bytes / ((double) div ));
  }
  else
  {
   //Else assume gigabytes
   unit = "G";
   __int64 div = 1 << 30;
   val = (int) (bytes / ((double) div ));
  }
  unit = unit + byteChar;
  const char * unitCharBuf = unit.GetBuffer();
  size.Format("%d%s", ((int) val), unitCharBuf);
  out = size.GetBuffer();
 }

}
```

However, when I compile this code I get the following error:

```
2>TxStatsTest.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A0005D4) "public: static class ATL::CStringT<char,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<char,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<char> > > __cdecl TxStats::GetTxRateStr(__int64)" (?GetTxRateStr@TxStats@@$$FSA?AV?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@DV?$ChTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@@@ATL@@_J@Z) referenced in function "public: void __clrcall AUnitTest::TxStatsTest::TestGetTxRateStr(void)" (?TestGetTxRateStr@TxStatsTest@AUnitTest@@$$FQ$AAMXXZ)
2>TxStatsTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class ATL::CStringT<char,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<char,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<char> > > __cdecl TxStats::GetTxRateStr(__int64)" (?GetTxRateStr@TxStats@@$$FSA?AV?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@DV?$ChTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@@@ATL@@_J@Z) referenced in function "public: void __clrcall AUnitTest::TxStatsTest::TestGetTxRateStr(void)" (?TestGetTxRateStr@TxStatsTest@AUnitTest@@$$FQ$AAMXXZ)
2>\trunk\<proj>\Debug\AUnitTest.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
2>Caching metadata information for c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\common7\ide\publicassemblies\microsoft.visualstudio.qualitytools.unittestframework.dll...
2>Build log was saved at "file://trunk\<proj>\AUnitTest\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
2>AUnitTest - 3 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Can anyone suggest why the Unit test project might not be linking against the obj files of the main project? (I have already specified the main project as a dependency of the unit test project)

Comment: Did any of the provided answers help?

Answer (score 3):

You can add

```
#pragma comment(lib, "TxStats.lib")
```

to your unit test project's stdafx.cpp to link against the other library.

Comment: what if it isn't built as a .lib but a .obj (or can I change it to .lib baring in mind my other project is an application and must remain so).

Comment: You can output a .lib import library without affecting anything else. Just specify a filename on the Advanced page of the Linker options for your project.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the *.obj files of the project you want to test to the linker inputs of the unit test project